# The length of trainPred is not correct in prediction function with R

Tags: r, naivebayes

This is my code for part of Naive Bayes a

```
trainPred<- predict(NBclassfier, newdata = train, type = "raw")
```

but I am getting wrong number for length of trainPred which two times biger than the actual size of the trainPre.

Even when I am using

```
trainPred<- predict(NBclassfier, newdata = train, type = "class")
```

I only get 0 for length of trainPred

so when I am running bellow code I get an error

```
trainTable <- table(train$prog, trainPred)
```

The Code for NBclassifer is `NBclassfier = naiveBayes(prog~., data= train)`

the whole code an an error

```
 library(caret)
library(e1071)

 set.seed(25)
trainIndex=createDataPartition(NaiveData$prog, p=0.8)$Resample1
train=NaiveData[trainIndex, ]
test=NaiveData[-trainIndex, ]
```

> ### check the balance

```
print(table(NaiveData$prog))



 0   1 
496 261
```

> ### Check the train table

```
print(table(train$prog))



 0   1 
388 218 

NBclassfier = naiveBayes(prog~., data= train)
trainPred <- predict(NBclassfier, newdata = train, type = "raw")
trainPred<- trainPred
trainTable <- table(train$prog, trainPred)


Error in table(train$prog, trainPred) :   all arguments must have the same length
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem and wanted to share the answer as well,

```
NBclassfier = naiveBayes(as.factor(prog)~., data= train)
confusionMatrix(as.factor(trainPred), as.factor(train$prog), mode = "prec_recall")
```

Justmake them Factor.